# how can I filter data cumulatively in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I'm relatively new to CakePHP and object oriented programming.  I have built apps in CakePHP before, but never to this extent, hence the reason I'm asking for help.

I have a large product management database, the user needs to be able to set filter criteria to find the closest product matches.

The products table contains category_id, manufacturer_id, type_id, status_id related to the respective tables.

I have a sidebar with dropdown boxes for each filter, and want all the filters to work together, for instance, if a manufacturer and product type is selected, display those filtered results, and change the status and category dropdowns to only contain options from the already filtered results.

In the past I have accomplished this by using a dynamic query setting conditions based on user input, appending where clauses each time a filter was applied.

so far I've only been able to get individually filtered results using

```
$this->Product->recursive = 0;
    $mid = (isset($this->params['named']['mid'])) ? $this->params['named']['mid'] : '';
    if(!empty($mid)){
        $this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => array('Product.manufacturer_id' => $mid),
            'limit' => 10
        );
    }
    $products = $this->paginate('Product');
    $this->set(compact('products'));
```

where 'mid' is the manufacturer id, and this is manually entering 'mid' in the url

How do I get cumulatively filter results if the user sets category_id, manufacturer_id, type_id, status_id or any combination?  And what queries would I use to repopulate the dropdowns?

(Eventually I will use ajax, but for now assume I have 4 dropdown boxes with a submit button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long way would be:

```
var $conditions = array();

if (isset($this->params['named']['mid']) && !empty($this->params['named']['mid'])){
   $conditions['Product.manufacturer_id'] = $this->params['named']['mid']);
}
if (isset($this->params['named']['catid']) && !empty($this->params['named']['catid'])){
   $conditions['Product.category_id'] = $this->params['named']['catid']);
}
if (isset($this->params['named']['statid']) && !empty($this->params['named']['statid'])){
   $conditions['Product.status_id'] = $this->params['named']['statid']);
}

$this->paginate['conditions'] = $conditions;
$this->paginate['limit'] = '10';
$this->set('products', $this->paginate('Product'));
```

Once you get the hang of that, you could put all your checks into a loop.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for, there were a few errors in syntax but the logic was there. Sorry it took so long to reply, this project had been delayed, but thanks for your help.   Ultimately CakeDCs search plugin will do exactly what I want, being able to filter by multiple attributes, cumulatively.   
 
thanks again!

Comment: @Tim Joyce
thanx it worked for me but the url is looking very bad ei
**localhost/businesses/index?category=&category=1&category=2&country=&country=1&country=2&state=&state=1&state=2&city=&city=1&city=2**

how to make this url SEO friendly.

Comment: @ErFaiyazAlam checkout http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements. you could access these url parameters the same way you access an id in the controller that's passed through the url `/somecontroller/3/param1/param2 ...etc

Comment: @Tim Joyce thanx for your reply. I will definitely do this.